# SignalR IIS hosting without OWIN StartUp.cs

Tags: signalr

Is it possible to host a SignalR application in IIS without using the OWIN start-up class ? I have an empty ASP.Net application with SignalR hub class and an html page in this same application.

If it is possible, how can we register the SignalR in OWIN pipeline ??

Answer (score 1):

Add following config entry:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup " value="false" />
```

Then add following line to start Owin once the connection string is available by setting this using a static public property in Owin Startup class.

```
WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8080");
```

WebApp will be in Microsoft.Owin.Hosting namespace.

Comment: For that you should use SignalR 1.1 as since 2.0 this is a dependency